# Selenium Webdriver and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm running a code on webdriver with TESTNG... the first test works perfectly fine but after when I try executing test2 ... the **driver.findelement** gets underlined in red and doesn't execute at all. Previous driver.findelement was brown but after test2 is blue, any reason to why its not working?

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void launchSandBoxTestingTestNG() throws InterruptedException{

    // Import FireFox Driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    // Open up Sandbox Page
    driver.get("****");

    // Enter Usename and Password

    // User
    driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("****");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Password
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("****");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Click Login Button
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void test2(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("****")).click();
    // When I try running this code above it underlines the find element in red 
   // When I run it on web driver the test2 syntax doesnt work
   //It gives me an option of casting an argument but not sure what that means  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The question is not very clear may be this might be the problem.
You are creating an WebDriver object inside a function.
Make WebDriver object global.

Example

```
public class test {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public void test1(){
 //test logic
}

public void test2(){
 // test logic
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi got it working finally! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I would also put "@Test(priority=1)" inside the "public void launchSandBoxTestingTestNg" and declare the webdriver inside the "launchSandBoxTestingTestNG" but outside the test methods

```
public void launchSandBoxTestingTestNG() throws InterruptedException{

// Import FireFox Driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


 @Test(priority=1)
 public void test1(){
// Open up Sandbox Page
driver.get("****");

// Enter Usename and Password

// User
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("****");
Thread.sleep(3000);

// Password
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("****");
Thread.sleep(3000);

// Click Login Button
driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void test2(){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("****")).click();
// When I try running this code above it underlines the find element in red 
   // When I run it on web driver the test2 syntax doesnt work
//It gives me an option of casting an argument but not sure what that means  
   }

}
```

Comment: @user6401108 No problem :)